# RequiredIf Conditional Validation for two variables in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model, required-field, foolproof-validation

I have a model class that is following

```
 public bool Saturday{ get; set; }

 public bool Sunday{ get; set; }

 public string Holiday{ get; set; }
```

In which I want to use the RequiredIf condition for the Holiday field using the both Saturday and Sunday fields. Can I use like following

```
   [RequiredIf("Sunday,Saturday",false)]
   public string Holiday{ get; set; }
```

So I don't know how to use the  RequiredIf condition in my model class, So please someone help me

Comment: you can create your own custom validation attribute in MVC this link will help you to create them http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301022/Creating-Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-MVC

Comment: Are your referring to foolproof's `RequiredIf` attribute? (if so, add the tag)

Comment: I added the tag, but doesn't work. Can you give any example code for use the foolproof's RequiredIf attribute? @Stephen Muecke

Comment: No, I meant to the list of tags at the bottom of the question (if you are using foolproof) If not, then what `RequiredIf` attribute are you using?

Comment: I don't know exactly because I am beginner to .Net Mvc. And RequiredIfAttribute class is used to it. And also by using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations , I have done the attribute.If you know the solution for it please help me @  Stephen Muecke

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Maybe try this in your model:

```
[Required]
public bool Saturday{ get; set; }

[Required]
public bool Sunday{ get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public bool SatSun
{
    get
    {
        return (!this.Saturday && !this.Sunday);
    }
}

[RequiredIf("SatSun",true)]
public string Holiday{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

If the need for more complex validation arises, I'd recommend implementing IValidatableObject.

```
public class YourModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public bool Saturday{ get; set; }

    public bool Sunday{ get; set; }

    public string Holiday{ get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var result = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (Saturday == false && Sunday == false && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Holiday))
        {
            result.Add(new ValidationResult("Holiday is required outside weekends"));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

If you combine property checks with IValidatableObject, be sure to note [this behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4769844/11599796).

Comment: Worth noting that passing property names as an array of strings for the second parameter of `ValidationResult`  will trigger validation CSS on bound properties.

Answer (score -2):

My Project has RequiredIf in it.

```
[Required]
public int SalesID { get; set; }

[RequiredIf("SalesID==1", ErrorMessage = "License is required.")]
public string License{ get; set; }
```

It shows error message 'License is required.' when License is left blank only if SalesID is 1. License cannot be blank if SalesID is 1.

For your code it should be something like

```
[RequiredIf("Sunday,Saturday",AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
public string Holiday{ get; set; }
```

It means if Sunday and Saturday are true you can allow Holiday property to be an Empty String.

Comment: It shows like "Does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments" @Sukanya

Comment: AllowEmptyStrings is not accepted, i.e the following type is accepted but does not work .   [RequiredIf("Sunday,Saturday",false)]

Comment: Give me some more details on the error. See the overloads of the RequiredIf Attribute.