# how to validate one field depends on another field in asp .net core 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working a asp .net core 6.0 project. I am doing a Opayo payment API.
https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo/spec/api-reference-0#operation/createTransaction

In this API,
There are some conditional required fields.

`postalCode` - **Not** required when `country` is IE.

`state` - Required when `country` is US.

`browserJavaEnabled` - Required if `browserJavascriptEnabled` is true.

`browserColorDepth` - Required if `browserJavascriptEnabled` is true.

`credentialType` **object** -  is required when  `Save` is true and so on..

Is there any package to add conditional Required field in asp .net core?
( for Required and NOT Required )

Comment: Related: [Conditionally required property using data annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354853/conditionally-required-property-using-data-annotations), [RequiredIf Conditional Validation for two variables in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336992/requiredif-conditional-validation-for-two-variables-in-mvc4)

Comment: FluentValidation at least can do that.