# How to validate all properties in a model at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, blazor

I have a Blazor application. In this application I have several models with various ValidationAttributes.

To validate these models I use an EditForm from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms. On this form there is a parameter Called EditContext where I call the Validate() method to validate my models.

The validation itself works fine. However the order of when validations are run seems to be based on the type, like this:

1. Required
2. Other(Like Range)
3. IValidatableObject

This results in Required validations being validated first and only after these are valid in the model the other validations are running.

What I want is for all validations to run at the same time.

Does anyone know how to achieve this in Blazor?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked on the guidelines ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-and-input-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Yes I have looked at that both while developing the concept I have now and again browsing through it in context of this

Answer (score 2):

> What I want is for all validations to run at the same time.

Not sure what you mean?  All registered validations are run when you call `Validate`.  There's has to be a sequence.  If you want to change the sequence then you need to write your own validator.

> the order of when validations are run seems to be based on the type

`Validate` on the edit context looks like this.  It simply invokes any delegates registered with the `OnValidationRequested` event.

```cs
    public event EventHandler<ValidationRequestedEventArgs>? OnValidationRequested;

    public bool Validate()
    {
        OnValidationRequested?.Invoke(this, ValidationRequestedEventArgs.Empty);
        return !GetValidationMessages().Any();
    }
```

`DataAnnotationsValidator` or whatever validator you use registers a handler on this event.

In your case the validator is finding fields to validate by searching through the properties in the `Model` (referenced in `EditContext`) for specifc attributes.  The first attribute it looks for is `Required`, ....

Answer (score 0):

I'm apparently not allowed to write comments - only answers - but you're right and what Shaun Curtis says is definitely wrong. For anybody doubting this [there's a gist here](https://gist.github.com/ncarandini/b0839175ce8c40c2b38605bb62844cbc).

When using `<DataAnnotationsValidator />` the validation attributes on the model are processed first - *only* once all of the attribute validation rules pass will the `IValidatableObject.Validate` method be called.

The functionality is by design - `IValidatableObject` is to validate the entire object once all of its properties have been filled out. [Why is IValidatableObject.Validate only called if property validation passes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769439/why-is-ivalidatableobject-validate-only-called-if-property-validation-passes)

Answer (score 0):

I think `Required` validation is checked first for a reason. All subsequent validations can and must be run only after the property has a value.

Otherwise, all the other validations would fail by default. It's the framework just reminding you that you forgot to type in a field. After you supply the value, then it goes on to validate its format and what not.

I hope that makes sense.